# Проверить два timestamp'а на принадлежность к одной дате

Tags: postgresql, дата, datetime, timestamp

В PostgreSQL БД в таблице есть поле published (timestamp with timezone).

Как средствами Python (py-postgresql) выбрать записи, у которых published попадает на заданную дату date? (Пусть timezone у date задаётся явно).

Нужно что-то вроде:

```
select = database.prepare(
    "SELECT id, link, title, summary, content, published "
    "FROM records "
    "WHERE published::date = $1::date"
)
…
date = dateutil.parser.parse(input())
records = select(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL="SELECT * FROM records WHERE published::date = {}::date".format($1)
rv = plpy.execute(SQL)
```